# Eigenvectors and the eigenvalues of a nonsymmetric tridiagonal matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, toeplitz-matrices

Is it possible to analytically evaluate the eigenvectors and the eigenvalues of a tridiagonal 3×3 matrix of the form:

$$H=\begin{bmatrix}
  0 & a & b \\ c & 0 & a \\ d & c & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: @Moo No. I don't want to use Mathematica software to calculate. I am looking forward to finding a simplify expression.

Comment: This is a $3\times 3$ matrix, but is penta-diagonal, or five-diagonal. Would be good to fix the title.

Comment: @MiladJangjan are the values a,b,c,d known? If not, are there some relations between them that you know? Can you share with us?

Comment: @user376343 Thank you for your comments. Actually, there is no relation between parameters.  As far as I noticed, the characteristic equation of such a matrix has a form $E^3+AE+B=0$. So the solutions can be determined. But I am looking forward to finding a straight solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $3\times 3$ Toeplitz matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4771064/eigenvectors-and-eigenvalues-of-3-times-3-toeplitz-matrix)