# eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $3\times 3$ Toeplitz matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is it possible to analytically evaluate the eigenvectors and the eigenvalues of a $3\times 3$ nonsymmetric Toeplitz matrix?
$$T=\begin{bmatrix}
  0 & a & b \\ c & 0 & a \\ d & c & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
(Clearly one can assume the diagonal to be $0$.)

Comment: Well, the characteristic equation is a depressed cubic equation and one could use a standard [radical formula for the solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Derivation_of_the_roots).... Getting the eigenvectors might be a whole bunch of case analysis, depending on what the eigenvalues look like.